# Dynamic MySQL Query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a way to make dynamic queries to my MySQL server. At the moment this is the code I use to update data on the server:

```
$deskAttr = json_decode($_POST["desk_attributes"]);

foreach($deskAttr as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE desk_attributes SET iw_standard=".$value->iw_standard.", avaya_standard=".$value->avaya_standard.", avaya_withcallid=".$value->avaya_withcallid.", avaya_withtransfer=".$value->avaya_withtransfer.", dual_screen=".$value->dual_screen.", air_conditioning=".$value->air_conditioning.", iw_obdialler=".$value->iw_obdialler." WHERE id=".$value->id;
    $conn->query($sql);
}
```

As you can see, the SQL column names are the same as the`deskAttr`keys. I'm looking for a way to make this line a loop so, that I don't need to change this line if I were to add more columns to the MySQL table.

It would look something like this:

```
$deskAttr = json_decode($_POST["desk_attributes"]);

foreach($deskAttr as $key => $value) {  
    $sql = "UPDATE desk_attributes SET";
    foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        $sql .= " $k = $value->$k ,";
    }
    $sql .= "WHERE id=".$value->id";
}
```

How would I write the code above so it will actually work?

---

**EDIT**

Maybe it will be helpful to know that`$deskAttr` is an array of objects, and the name of the columns are the same as the name of the objects keys.

Here is what I mean in pseudo code:

```
foreach($object in $deskAttr) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET ";
    foreach($key in $object) {
        if($key != "id")
            $sql .= "$key = $object->$key, ";
    }
    $sql .= "WHERE id = $object->id;
    $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Obviously this would add an extra comma at the end of the query before the WHERE part, but hopefully you get what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You should really switch to prepared statements for the values and a white-list for the column names to avoid sql injection.

Comment: You can't bind column names via prepared statement. So if you're gonna put a variable string in your SQL query string, juste escape them correctly and you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with slight change in your code by using PHP's [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

Take a blank array, concatenate the update parameters to it.

And then if is not [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), `implode()` to get string.

**Updated Code:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE desk_attributes SET ";
foreach ($deskAttr as $key => $value) {
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value); // $links is database connection string.
 $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $key); // $links is database connection string.
 $updtAttrs[] = $key ." = '" . $value . "'";
}
$sql .= ! empty($updtAttrs) ? implode(', ', $updtAttrs) : '';
$sql .= " WHERE id=" . $value->id;
```

Comment: This code is **_very_** insecure. It's wide open to SQl Injections. You should use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating user inputs directly like this. You should also have a list of allowed column names.

Comment: No it's not. Stop being a prepared-statement-nazi and go read `mysqli_real_escape_string` documentation

Comment: @KiJéy - Maybe you should check the time line of the comment and the edits of the post. **1.** When I wrote the comment,  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` weren't included in the answer _at all_. **2.** The `$key` is _still_ totally unescaped, which _still_ makes it 100% open for SQL Injections. Btw, there actually are situations where `mysqli_real_escape_string()` isn't enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have updated the answer after getting comment from you.

Comment: The code is still open for injections, as you can see in my last comment.

Comment: If I post some data that looks like this: `$_POST['something hello'] = 'world'`, that query would break. As mentioned earlier, you should have a white list of allowed column names. It a column name isn't white listed, don't add it to the query. Never trust user input.